# Add shortcut icon to a Gatsby site

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

[image: Windows cmd window with errors]

I'm creating a site with `gatsby.js` and I'm almost done, and I'd like to add shortcut icon but I don't know how.

Comment: in shortcut icon do you mean favicon?

Answer (score 1):

Install [`gatsby-plugin-manifest`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-manifest/), add it and configure within `gatsby-config.js` file.

Add `icon` path [as explained at the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-manifest/#configure-icons-and-their-generations---required):

```
const config = require('./src/config');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-manifest',
      options: {
        icon: './src/images/logo.png',
      },
    }
  ],
};
```

Comment: We can't guess what is the error, you should edit your question with `edit` button with full details of the problem you face.

Comment: I added an image

Answer (score 0):

You can use gatsby-plugin-manifest.